# CoreLocation WidgetKit

Tags: swiftui, core-location, widgetkit

I'm having troubles getting `CoreLocation` working in `WidgetKit`. I was able to do so using an `ObservableObject` class in a SwiftUI app just fine. Now I'm not sure how to do so with a widget.

I added `LocationManager` to my `TimelineEntry` and then called the `requestLocation` function in `getTimeline()` but it didn't work either. I'm not seeing any updates in my Widget. I added the proper keys to my widget as explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/accessing-location-information-in-widgets).

```swift
import Foundation
import CoreLocation
import WidgetKit

class LocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var location: CLLocation?
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
    }
    
    func requestUpdate(_ completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.last else { return }
        self.location = location
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

[image: CoreLocation SwiftUI app]

[image: CoreLocation Widget Fail]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved my location manager to `TimelineProvider` and added my variables to my widgets `TimelineEntry`. `CoreLocation` is now updating correctly.

[image]